# What can cause increase in "time spent on php"

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, php, web

While monitoring a traffic decrease in the last couple of hours, I've noticed a hugh increase in 'time spent on php' through newrelic:
[image]

Not sure how/where to start debug this. The requests-per-min and server load have both decreased since this started, which makes me think about something related to network.

Disk I/O, CPU, Web External:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `The requests-per-min has actually decreased as the server load.`? Do you mean the server load has decreased also? I'd start by looking at top to see what takes so long. Also there looking at the logs is a good idea. There are a lot of things that can be responsible for that.

Comment: @lsmooth yes meant server load also decreased. `top` doesn't show anything out of the ordinary. Which logs would you start with?

Comment: Apache's error-logs, php-logs if you have, database-logs, slow-query-logs etc. Do you see php-errors in newrelic (in Events -> Errors under the PHP-Application)?

Comment: Do any periodic processes that may do heavy disk IO start at 3am? (Or even a scheduled RAID controller scrub/patrol read) If Newrelic can tell the difference between time spent on PHP, and time spent on database queries, then I can only assume it's pulling this information directly from the host and '1000ms spent on PHP' actually means the PHP code took 1000ms instead of 500ms, so I can't see how it can be down to network. (Unless your PHP code is performing network related tasks). I read that as your PHP code is actually taking twice as long to run (which suggests server resource problems)

Comment: @USDMatt No heavy disk IO start at 3am, but I did add more monitoring graphs to the question. Maybe these help you direct me better? The reason I'm 'blaming' network, is it appears resources are all lower. This is a webserver that receives most of the traffic from Google, and the traffic decrease is 1:1 inline with the jump in time spent on PHP.

Comment: Hmm, well the less requests makes some sense as longer app response times (~1.5 seconds) means you can handle less requests per minute. The fact that no other resource use goes up and CPU use goes down, though, suggests that the server really isn't doing anything else that would account for PHP taking longer. My only other guess would be that the PHP code itself is taking to other hosts, and it's those external calls which have been slowed down. At this point I'd probably add profiling to the PHP code to see where it is spending the time.

Comment: @USDMatt If external calls were responsible  newrelic would display that as in that case Web External would be the one the time is spent on and php would be low. It's just plain php that takes longer. Is assume the code did not change did it? What is possible is that the external calls return differnet data that results in php taking longer to with the data. But generally I would try profiling the php-code too. Also newrelic should be able which requests take so long.

Comment: Code didn't change and external calls can't really return data that will cause such more time to handle. Also, from my Geo-Location it doesn't appear the php is actually taking more time to process. Might it be that newrelic is also counting some sort of network time response inside this variable?

Answer (score 0):

check your access / request logs (/var/log/httpd/ for default redhat/centos) which pages are being requested. It could be you are serving pages that cause more load.

you could also test your network connectivity with the basic network commands.

Comment: I'm actually seeing less load, and am 99.9% sure nothing changed with which pages are being accessed. Can you elaborate a bit on `basic network commands` ?

Comment: u can use `ping` to check for the obvious am i connected to internet and do I have packetloss. And you could also use `wget` from the commandline to test your download speeds. a third option is `iperf` for throughput testing. check out this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-test-internet-connection-download-upload-speed/) for some examples of usage